# What does it mean when the specs say "REST API implementation"?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

Well for example, the client makes software with a "REST API implementation" using Java EE.

I thought web apps by default are implementing REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as an alternative, a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) API implementation could be used.

Comment: sorry for this noobish question sir, do I have to install anything to implement REST or SOAP? or is it just a design I need to conform to?

Comment: Well, if you are willing to reinvent the wheel, in both cases is it just a design you need to conform to. If on the other hand, you prefer to avoid wasting your time reinventing stuff, then you can use what is already available: JAX-RS for Rest stuff, and JAX-WS for SOAP stuff

Comment: Btw, I'll be using spring, is JAX-RS compating with Spring?

Comment: Yes, it is, on the other hand, Spring has its own (non standard) REST support: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/